# How to stop data being retrieved when my component is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I only want the data to be displayed once the generate joke (click here for a chuckle) button is clicked, however it is retrieved once the page loads. How do I stop this?

```
`import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [joke, getJoke] = useState(" ")
  const newJoke = () => {
    fetch("http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random")
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(result2 => {
        console.log(result2)
        getJoke(result2.value.joke)
      })
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    newJoke()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="jokeSection">
      <h1>Chuck norris jokes</h1>
      <h3>{joke}</h3>
      <button onClick={() => newJoke()}>Click here for a chuckle</button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;`
```

And is this a good way of coding? should I use a different function such as componentDidMount?

Comment: because thats how useEffect works. Page loads and whatever is in useEffect will run on load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
`import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [joke, getJoke] = useState(" ")
  const newJoke = () => {
    fetch("http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random")
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(result2 => {
        console.log(result2)
        getJoke(result2.value.joke)
      })
  }
  useEffect(() => {

  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="jokeSection">
      <h1>Chuck norris jokes</h1>
      <h3>{joke}</h3>
      <button onClick={() => newJoke()}>Click here for a chuckle</button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;`
```

Remove it from useEffect and keep it onClick and that should do it.As mentioned in the comments , useEffect will run everytime the page loads basically.

Comment: Thank you! that helps. I'm a beginner to react so just learning. Would you say this a good way of coding so far or would you recommend any major improvements?

Comment: Actually I think it looks pretty decent so far . I would say instead of naming it getJoke,name it setJoke. Since you're setting it to the state and not getting from it. Less confusing for you. But so far so good keep it up @SharozeKhan

Comment: and Also componentDidMount only works in class components I think. You're using functional components. If you use functional components you always use the useState hook

Comment: Thanks for you help and the info! appreciate it

Comment: you can improve this code by removing redundant  ``.then``

Comment: @sumit which line is this as I thought both `.then` are needed?

Comment: @Kevin.a quick question, can I implement error handling in functional components? i've only seen examples in class components.

Comment: you havent use useffect for side effect changes , so  this method will fetch data forever if there is any rendering issue

Answer (score 0):

I would rather like to maintain 2 states for joke toggle and joke data  like below.

The effect hook called useEffect is used to fetch the data with axios from the API and to set the data in the local state of the component with the state hook's update function. The promise resolving happens with async/await.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [joke, setJoke] = useState(0);
  const [jokeData, setJokeData] = useState("");

  function newJoke(){
    setJoke(joke=>joke+1);
  }

  useEffect( () => {
    (async function loadJoke() {
     if(joke>0){ 
     const response=await axios.get('https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random');
     setJokeData(response.data.value.joke);
     }
    })();
    }, [joke]);

  return (
    <div className="jokeSection">
      <h1>Chuck norris jokes</h1>
      <h3>{jokeData}</h3>
      <button onClick={() => newJoke()}>Click here for a chuckle</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for this but unfortunately I can not use axios the task requires me to purely use reactjs but I appreciate the advice.

Comment: " the task requires me to purely use reactjs" why  you cannot use axios? is it some coding test you are giving

Comment: it's not a test, just a exercise that I am doing.

Comment: just replace axios with fetch , not an issue at all